# How to embed a React application into a basic HTML page?

Tags: html, networking, iframe

The target site will not fully load inside the iframe element I've assigned it to:

```
<iframe
    id="modalMapView"
    class="hidden"
    src="https://syringemap.firebaseapp.com/"
    title="Syringe Map live application"
    scrolling="no"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-same-origin"
></iframe>
```

If you visit the firebase app, you can see that it takes a bit of time, but eventually will load an additional menu and map. Are there any particular attributes I could add to the iframe that will help it move forward in the loading process?

EDIT: Photo for reference - this is what the iframe renders in my viewport: [iframe render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLlT.png), and this is what it needs to render: [firebase application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaAkN.png)

Comment: What isn't fully loading? The website appears the same in the iframe as it does when I load it directly.

Comment: @ReganKarlewicz added photo references, thanks!

Comment: Both loads appear like the iframe render for me. Do you have an authorization token for the map data something stored in a cookie? Or somewhere else the iframe wouldn't be able to access?

Comment: @ReganKarlewicz Oh alright... I am just now seeing that it renders the blank version on other browser instances, so I'm guessing it's like you said, I was likely given authorization for this particular project for development. Will follow up with the team about this tomorrow, thanks again for checking it out

Comment: Think I figured it out. I had geolocation turned off, which was causing the map to not load. I posted an answer! Maybe the map should display a "Cannot access location" warning when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `allow` property on the iframe:

```
<iframe
  id="modalMapView"
  class="hidden"
  src="https://syringemap.firebaseapp.com/"
  title="Syringe Map live application"
  scrolling="no"
  allow="geolocation"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-same-origin"
></iframe>
```

Comment: There we go, that works perfectly! Thanks again